# Dropdown attributes values are not updating in database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, dropdown-attribute, multi-vendor

we are using following code to update custom attribute values .attribute code : "**mp_local_shipping_price [ Text field ]**" , attribute label : Local. its working fine

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('mp_local_shipping_charge');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}


function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controllers.php**

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);    
        $product->setData('mp_local_shipping_charge',$upd_local);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'mp_local_shipping_charge');       

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

we are using following code to update custom attribute values .attribute code : "**cod_available [ Drop Down ]**" , attribute label : Cod . **its not updating.**

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<select id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" name= "cod[]" "> 

<option value="0" <?php if($pro->getCod()==0) { echo "selected";} ?>>No</option> 
<option value="1"<?php if($pro->getCod()==1) { echo "selected";} ?>>Yes</option> 

</select> 

<?php endif; ?>

<input type="hidden" name="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getCod(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedcod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="cod_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**Script**

```
function hideResetCod(product_id,codold) { 

var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuecod).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currcod).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}




function updateFieldCod(product_id) 
{ 
var codId = '#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedcod_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/')?>'; 
$cod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
$currcod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
if($cod!=$currcod) {
$wk_jq(currcod).val($cod); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldCodAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_cod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        $product->setData('cod_available',$upd_cod);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'cod_available');  
     //   $product->setCod($upd_cod);

        $product->save();

        echo $cod = $product->getCod();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

we are using following code to update both custom attributes. Local [textfield] attribute is working & Cod [dropdown] attribute is not working.

**code to update one product**

**Phtml**

```
<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateAllFields('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**script**

```
<script>

function updateAllFields(product_id) {
        jQuery('#price_reset_button_'+product_id).css('display','none');
        if(jQuery("#price_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#curr_"+product_id).val())
              updateFieldPrice(product_id);

        if(jQuery("#specialprice_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#specialcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id);
            updateField(product_id);
        if(jQuery("#local_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#localcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldLocal(product_id);
        if(jQuery("#regional_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#regionalcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldRegional(product_id);
        if(jQuery("#state_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#statecurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldState(product_id); 
        if(jQuery("#cod_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#codcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldCod(product_id); 
        if(jQuery("#qty_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#currqty_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldqty(product_id);

</script>
```

**controller.php**

```
public function singlerowupdateAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $speprice= $this->getRequest()->getParam('speprice');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quantity');
        $mp_local_shipping_charge = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mp_local_shipping_charge');
        $cod_available = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod_available');
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
       $product->setPrice($price);
       $product->setSpecialPrice($price);
       $product->setQty($qty);
       $product->setLocal($mp_local_shipping_charge);
       $product->setCod($cod_available);
       $product->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

**code to update multiple products**
code to update all products attributes by clicking on single update button

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');

        $local= $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $regional= $this->getRequest()->getParam('regional');
        $state= $this->getRequest()->getParam('state');
        $cod= $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');

        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->setMpLocalShippingCharge($local[$key]);
    $product->setMpRegionalShippingCharge($regional[$key]);
    $product->setMpStateShippingCharge($state[$key]);
    $product->setCod($cod[$key]);

$product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you param is `cod` not `cod_available` check your jquery here `parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod},`

just change in controller it will start working

`$cod_available = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');`

and update that too `$product->setCod($cod[$key]);` to `$product->setCodAvailable($cod[$key]);`

Comment: sorry, did't worked for me

Comment: where is problem single update or multiple multiple?

Comment: both are giving me problem

Comment: seems by default, it showing "NO" for all products in frontend

Comment: did you check this attribute `Used in Product Listing` is `yes` in admin side

Comment: `Used in Product Listing' it was "NO", now i changed to "yes" , but still its displaying "NO" for all products

Comment: reindex the data.

Comment: okay, i will do now

Comment: sorry, it didt worked....

Comment: is it displaying properly or not?

Comment: stil its displaying "NO' for all values.